# Memory reordering in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory, msdn

There is an example in msdn magazine article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx

```
class BoxedInt
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
class LazyInit
{
  volatile BoxedInt _box;
  public int LazyGet()
  {
    var b = _box;  // Read 1
    if (b == null)
    {
      lock(this)
      {
        b = new BoxedInt();
        b.Value = 42; // Write 1
        _box = b;     // Write 2
      }
    }
    return b.Value; // Read 2
  }
}
```

It is stated that:

> In this example, LazyGet is always guaranteed to return “42.” However,
>   if the _box field were not volatile, LazyGet would be allowed to
>   return “0” for two reasons: the reads could get reordered, or the
>   writes could get reordered.

I understand why the function can return 0 when "Write 1" and "Write 2" are reordered, but how can it return 0 when reads are reordered assuming that writes are not reordered. And how can reads be even reordered taking into account that there is a data dependency?

Comment: Note that if you read the second part of the article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx) you'll see that in the end the Microsoft .NET uses a strong memory model and all the writes aren't reordered (he checks it on x64, Itanium (that has a weak memory model) and ARM.

Comment: Is is an implementation detail, is not it? Anyway I try to understand the ECMA-334 memory model.

Comment: yes, it is implementation detail. Mono doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: And I too can't find what exactly he means with "the reads could get reordered".

Comment: What memory model is assumed by this question? ECMA or the Microsoft CLR?

Comment: ECMA (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) provides almost no guarantees. It does not talk about data dependencies at all. It does not even preclude introducing reads or writes (the latter is deadly and a spec oversight in my opinion).

Comment: Note, that reads with a data dependencies *can* be reordered. The system can speculate what `_box` points to and read from that location before reading the value of `_box`.

Comment: From my understanding if _box points to null then the system cannot to speculate anything. If _box points to an object then writes already executed and assuming that they were not reordered _box.b has to be 42

Comment: @user580067 the system can speculatively read the address 0x1234 and hope that _box has that address. If it doesn't, reread. if it does the speculation succeeds and time was reversed. That's why it's called speculation - you can just read anything at all and use it only if it later turns out to be valid.